# how do I get around the 403 error when trying to push files to a repository on github?

Tags: github

I see the following error message (Windows, Powershell)

```
PS C:\Users\family\Desktop\index.html> 
  git push origin main
  remote: Permission to assylum6/assignment1.git denied to AlvaroMakobi.
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/assylum6/assignment1/': 
    The requested URL returned an error: 403
```

Comment: The recommended (I think) way is to use an ssh key:  [connecting-to-github-with-ssh](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) I am assuming this is your repository - if not you have to pursue other options or ask the repository own to add you as contributor.

Answer (score 0):

Check first, in a git bash session (not Powershell) if you have cached credentials:

```
git config --global credential.helper
xxx  <=== take note of that value

# replace xxx by that value
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-xxx get
```

If `AlvaroMakobi` is your GitHub account, then you don't own `assylum6/assignment1`, and you possibly need to [fork that repository](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/about-forks) in order to push to your fork (using HTTPS or SSH).